# Possibly recoverable warning exit code from extractor

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Response while initiating a translate:

```json
{
    "bucketKey": "suresh_ferzia_india_120",
    "objectId": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:suresh_ferzia_india_120/:delman.stp",
    "objectKey": ":delman.stp",
    "sha1": "4e0bb47f3c7e1fd22138040bde9e9be130ea2095",
    "size": 930988,
    "contentType": "application/octet-stream",
    "location": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/suresh_ferzia_india_120/objects/:delman.stp"
}
```

Everything seems to work fine with the above API. But when I try fetching it's status using get manifest API, I get the following error:

```json
{
    "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6c3VyZXNoX2ZlcnppYV9pbmRpYV8xMjAvOmRlbG1hbi5zdHA",
    "derivatives": [
        {
            "hasThumbnail": "false",
            "name": "_delman.stp",
            "progress": "complete",
            "messages": [
                {
                    "type": "error",
                    "message": "Possibly recoverable warning exit code from extractor: -536870943",
                    "code": "TranslationWorker-RecoverableInternalFailure"
                }
            ],
            "outputType": "svf",
            "status": "failed"
        }
    ],
    "hasThumbnail": "false",
    "progress": "complete",
    "type": "manifest",
    "region": "US",
    "version": "1.0",
    "status": "failed"
}
```

Could someone help me understand this error?

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following:

- confirm that the size of the uploaded object (930988) is the same as the actual file on your system; if they're different, perhaps there's some issue in the upload logic and the content of the object in the Forge bucket is corrupted
- try removing the `:` from the file name as this could be causing issues as well
- if possible, share the STEP file with us via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` (confidentially; we would not share it with anyone outside of Autodesk) so that we can debug the issue on our end